# How to exit Python Turtle Window when key pressed

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to get my turtle window to close after I press the "e" key on my keyboard (on VS Code). When I run my code, everything works fine until after the turtle window pops up, and after the turtle draws what I asked it to, nothing happens when I press E.

```
import random
import turtle
import keyboard

# Starting to draw the actual card
screen = turtle.getscreen()
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.screensize(canvwidth=600, canvheight=600, bg=None)
# my_turtle.hideturtle()

my_turtle.pendown()
my_turtle.backward(40)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.fd(100)
# time.sleep(10)
# turtle.exitonclick()
if keyboard.read_key() == "e":
    turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is most likely due to the way the keyboard module handles keyboard inputs.

A potential solution to your issue could be using turtle's built-in `onkey` function. It waits for a specified key to be pressed and then runs given function.

```py
import turtle

def close_window():
    turtle.bye()

# Starting to draw the actual card
screen = turtle.getscreen()
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.screensize(canvwidth=600, canvheight=600, bg=None)

my_turtle.pendown()
my_turtle.backward(40)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.fd(100)

turtle.onkey(close_window, "e")  # Run the close_window function when 'e' is pressed.
turtle.listen()  # Start listening for key presses.
turtle.mainloop()  # Keep the window open until the 'e' key is pressed.
```

Comment: This did not end up working, but I see what you mean using the onkey function.